# How to avoid duplicate in random query result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I need to select 4 random ids from the table, but problem is that they are sometimes duplicated how to avoid that? I have tried to use DISTINCT but with no results here is the code.As for CMS I am using opencart.

```
<h1>similar products</h1>
<?php
$id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
$cur_jur = $this->db->query("SELECT `value` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "currency` WHERE currency_id = '1'");
$cur_fiz = $this->db->query("SELECT `value` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "currency` WHERE currency_id = '3'");
$max_symb = 25;
$fee_id = $product_id;
$product_sql_test_fee = $this->db->query("SELECT `category_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` WHERE `product_id`='".$fee_id."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10");
$feed_id = $product_sql_test_fee->row['category_id'];
$i=1;
$imax = 5;
$products_id = '';
while ($i < $imax) 
{
    $product_fee = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT `product_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` WHERE `category_id`='".$feed_id."' AND NOT `product_id` = '".$products_id."'  GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10");
    if(isset($product_fee->row['product_id']))
    {
        $pr_id[$i] = $product_fee->row['product_id'];
    }

    $pr_id_[$i] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($pr_id[$i]);
    $products_id .= $pr_id[$i].',';
    $product_duplicate = explode(',',$products_id);
    if ($product_duplicate[$i] == $pr_id[$i])
    {

    }


    //if ($product_duplicate[$i] == $pr_id[$i]){ //echo 'Duplicate';
    //continue;} else {
    //foreach ($product_duplicate as $id) {
    //if ($id == $pr_id[$i]) continue;
    //}
    //$price_plus = $pr_id_[$i]['price'] + ($pr_id_[$i]['price'] * 0.20);
    //$price_minus = $pr_id_[$i]['price'] - ($pr_id_[$i]['price'] * 0.20);
    //$price_of_product = (int)$price / $cur_fiz->row['value'];
    //if ($price_of_product < $price_plus && $price_of_product > $price_minus) {
    //echo $pr_id[$i].'||'.$price_minus.'||'.$price_plus.'||'.$pr_id_[$i]['price'].'||'.$price_of_product.'<br/>';
    //}

    $price_plus = $pr_id_[$i]['price'] + ($pr_id_[$i]['price'] * 0.30);
    $price_minus = $pr_id_[$i]['price'] - ($pr_id_[$i]['price'] * 0.30);
    $price_of_product = (int)$price / $cur_fiz->row['value'];
    if ($price_of_product < $price_plus && $price_of_product > $price_minus   ) 
    {
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: since you are running the same query in a while loop, it will get duplicates. remove the while loop and then add a for loop to go through each row of the query and insert your while loop logic there

Comment: have you tried order by rand() GROUP BY id and limit 4? Format your code it's messy and unclear.

Comment: You have used both DISTINCT (which should bring back distinct rows) and GROUP BY (which is used with aggregate functions but can also be abused to remove duplicates), which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by category_id problem will be resolved.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `product_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` WHERE `category_id`='".$feed_id."' AND NOT `product_id` = '".$products_id."'  GROUP BY `category_id`
```

Comment: Pretty sure that won't run since product_id isn't contained in the group by, he'll get an error. His sql looks correct, it's more likely that it's in a loop and randomly selecting the same thing twice, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: @MikeC. one product may have different category and because of this he may get duplicate entry.

Comment: Hello all again. Thank you for responses. I have tried group by category and got an error like this.

Comment: hi please post your sql query by echo "SELECT DISTINCT `product_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` WHERE `category_id`='".$feed_id."' AND NOT `product_id` = '".$products_id."'  GROUP BY `product_id` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10"

Comment: Unknown: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. What can I do?

Comment: Hi again. I tried to use the for loop as suggested. But got the same result the indexes are still sometimes duplicated. For example: 4767. So what can I do about it?

Comment: hi @BogdanOnyshenko plz print/log your query and attach here  or you can just copy echo section and provide me result echo "SELECT `category_id` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` WHERE `product_id`='".$fee_id."' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10"; so that i can help you

Comment: category97 its doesn't change.

Comment: $cat_id[]=0;
      foreach ($cat_id as &$j) {
    $j = $j + 1;
$cat_id[$j] = $product_sql_test_fee->row['category_id'];

echo 'category'.$cat_id[$j];
}